# How to optimize mysql on left join

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I try to explain a very high level

I have two complex `SELECT` queries(for the sake of example I reduce the queries to the following):

```
SELECT id, t3_id FROM  t1;
SELECT t3_id, MAX(added) as last FROM t2 GROUP BY t3_id;
```

query 1 returns 16k rows and query 2 returns 15k

each queries individually takes less than `1 second` to compute

However what I need is to sort the results using column `added` of query 2, when I try to use `LEFT join`

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.t3_Id
FROM
    t1
        LEFT JOIN
    (SELECT t3_id, MAX(added) as last FROM t2 GROUP BY t3_id) AS t_t2 
        ON t_t2.t3_id = t1.t3_id
GROUP BY t1.t3_id
ORDER BY t_t2.last
```

However, the execution time goes up to over a `1 minute`.

I like to understand the reason

what is the cause of such a huge explosion?

**NOTE:**

ALL the used columns on every table have been indexed
e.g. :

- table t1 has index on id,t3_Id
- table t2 has index on t3_id and added

**EDIT1**

after @Tim Biegeleisen suggestion, I change the query to the following now the query is executing in about 16 seconds. If I remove the `ORDER BY` it query gets executed in less than 1 seconds. The problem is that `ORDER BY` the sole reason for this.

```
SELECT 
    t1.id, t1.t3_Id
FROM
    t1
        LEFT JOIN
    t2 ON t2.t3_id = t1.t3_id

GROUP BY t1.t3_id
ORDER BY MAX(t2.added)
```

Comment: You have no `ON` condition here, meaning that you are doing a cross join of `t1` and a derived table, whose result likely has several hundred thousand rows.

Comment: Your `LEFT JOIN` lacks an `ON` clause. So, you're probably getting a combinatorial explosion from the join, resulting in an enormous intermediate table. You're also misusing the nasty nasty MySQL extension to `GROUP BY`. Read this. https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen appologies , that was a typo mistake, I've edited the question

Comment: @OllieJones appologies , that was a typo mistake, I've edited the question

Comment: If this is a "groupwise max", you cannot trust the output.  The optimizer is free to provide any `t1.id` since the `GROUP BY` does not include it.

Comment: Please explain the _intent_ of the query; it is hard to unravel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though table `t2` has an index on column `t3_id`, when you join `t1` you are actually joining to a derived table, which either can't use the index, or can't use it completely effectively.  Since `t1` has 16K rows and you are doing a `LEFT JOIN`, this means the database engine will need to scan the entire derived table for each record in `t1`.

You should use MySQL's `EXPLAIN` to see what the exact execution strategy is, but my suspicion is that the derived table is what is slowing you down.

Comment: ok that was very helpful. I changed the query to NOT use derived table . I've updated the answer (EDIT1), it increased the speed by 4 times.

Comment: this is the closest explanation to the answer. thx mate, finally  I've figured it out. still it takes 3 sec, but better than it was and 3 sec , well can be used ...

Answer (score 0):

The correct query should be:

```
SELECT
  t1.id,
  t1.t3_Id,
  MAX(t2.added) as last
FROM t1
  LEFT JOIN t2 on t1.t3_Id = t2.t3_Id
GROUP BY t2.t3_id
ORDER BY last;
```

This is happen because a temp table is generating on each record.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could try to order everything after the records are available. Maybe:

```
select * from (
select * from 
(select t3_id,max(t1_id) from t1 group by t3_id) as t1
left join (select t3_id,max(added) as last from t2 group by t3_id) as t2 
on t1.t3_id = t2.t3_id ) as xx
order by last
```

Comment: Remember that you should have indexes on both tables (t1 and t2) with t3_id as the first column in the index.